# Fotorama 4 : Number of preloaded images

Tags: preload, fotorama

Is it possible to define the number of images to preload?

I think by default the first 3 image is automatically loaded.
There was this option Fotorama 3.0 (preload options)

Thank

Answer (score 0):

It seems next and previous images are preloaded by default.